# ObjectOutputStream human-readable

Tags: java, file-io, arraylist, io

I am trying to read and write an ArrayList to a file, and currently using ObjectOutputStream to write to the file.

```
fout = new FileOutputStream(file);
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);

oos.writeObject(arraylist);
fout.close();
```

The `arraylist` variable is an ArrayList of ojects. This method works fine and all, but it prints to the file in a format that is not human-readable.

Is there any way to achieve the same functionality (with relative ease) so that the object is written to the file in a human-readable manner?

Comment: Basically, `ObjectOutputStream` is the wrong class for what you are trying to do.  There are various alternatives that may work, depending on what these objects that you are trying to write really are.  But (AFAIK) there is nothing that will cope (adequately) with *any* object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you need to do is use a PrintWriter, and cycle through your array list printing to the new file each time.  Try:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(outputFile);

for (int i=0;i<<name>.length;i++){ 
writer.println(<ArrayListName>[i].getString(), + "\t" + <ArrayListName>[i].getFirstInt() + "\t" + <name>.[i].getSecondInt +<etc...>); 
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

You can use a Json representation, which is human readable.

For instance using Jackson:

```
ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer();
ow.writeValue(fout, arraylist);
```

To read back:

```
List<E> myObjects = new ObjectMapper().readValue(inputStream, 
                      new TypeReference<List<E>>(){});
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using `ObjectOutputStream`,it writes a binary serialized version of that data to file ,which is non-human readable. However you can use `BufferedWriter` for performing the same.

```
          //Sample code

     try{
            ArrayList<YourObject> yourObjectList;
           BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:/yourPath/fileName.txt"));
             for (YourObject oneObjAtATime : yourObjectList) {
                  writer.write(oneObjAtATime.toString());
                 }
       }catch(Exception e){
            throw new Exception("error");
            }
```